# Pick a date from the datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a car rental application I am writing. I am having some issue. Basically I want a user to pick a date from dateTimePicker2 then dateTimePicker1 I then want to subtract those numbers from eachother and store it in car. I have created a button that will multiple the per day charge then display it in a label but I just having an issue with this part.

```
carRental = dateTimePicker2 - dateTimePicker1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot subtract a datetimepicker instance from another. You need to use the selected values, like this:

```
var timeSpan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
var rentalDays = timeSpan.Days;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
DateTime dateTime2 = dateTimePicker2.Value;

DateTime dateTime1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;

var carRental = dateTime2 - dateTime1;
```

[DateTimePicker.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) at MSDN.